# Query makes my page not respond

Tags: php, mysql, performance, select

I am not sure why but my MySQL query below, makes my page not respond and I get that box saying this page has became unresponsive. I am wondering what would be the easiest way to make sure that this does not happen.

```
public function audioplayer($id)
{
    $r_hostname = "192.***.**.***";
    $r_username = "c**";
    $r_password = "*******";
    $link = mysql_connect($r_hostname,$r_username,$r_password);

    $a_hostname = "192.168.***.***";


    $db = mysql_select_db('asterisk', $link);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recording_log WHERE start_time LIKE '".date("Y-m-d")."%' AND filename LIKE 'IL_%-%". $id ."' LIMIT 3",$link);


    #$result = mysql_query("select * from recording_log WHERE filename LIKE 'IL_%-%".$id."'",$link);

    if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }   
    if($result != '')
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            foreach($row as $column => $value) {
                $array[type] ="wav";    
                $array[$column]= $value;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $linktwo = mysql_connect($a_hostname,$r_username,$r_password);

        $dbtwo = mysql_select_db('asterisk', $linktwo);

        $resulttwo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recording_log WHERE start_time LIKE '".date("Y-m-d")."%' AND filename LIKE 'IL_%-%". $id ."' LIMIT 3",$linktwo);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resulttwo, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            foreach($row as $column => $value) {
                $array[type] ="mp3";
                $array[$column]= $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the query is causing the problem? Have you tried running the query against the database directly? If so, how long did it take, and how does that time compare with your PHP _max_execution_time_ configuration value?

Answer (score 1):

Feels like there's a syntax error here:

```
$array[type] ="mp3";
```

Did you mean:

```
$array[$type] ="mp3";
$array["type"] ="mp3";
```

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: @RussellHarrower Even `for ($i = 0; $a < $b; $s++)` is right. Syntactically right. Not logically right!

Comment: 1. You might wanted to use `$type` but accidentally used `type`. 2. You might wanted a string `type` for the index, but accidentally used `type`.

Comment: I am downvoting for two reasons. First, the original answer is an issue, but doesn't really address the slowness that was the OP's focus. Second (and more importantly) the edit added by @NullPoiиteя is spammy and unrelated. This does not address the problem of unresponsiveness. At _best_, that edit should be a comment. Even better, NullPoiиteя should note that the information has been added to the tag wiki and does not need to be repeated on every `mysql_*` question.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins ___spammy and unrelated___. really??? really ???.... see code is question again ..... and  its perfectly fine   to tell about deprecated api

Comment: @GeorgeCummins This is bad.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins if there is `mysql_*` in code in question then there is nothing wrong  to add ...and i am done